# CLion: how to fetch source file containing the main() associated to current target?

Tags: clion

I'm using CLion for hosting my current C++ project.
I have a hierarchy of directories that is compiled using CMakeLists files. add_subdirectory() is invoked to run through the complete arborescence.

I end up having a long number of targets on my list (top-left on the UI).
My problem is the following: when I select a target to compile, there is nothing (AFAIK) that lets me go directly to either:

1. the corresponding target definition located in one of the CMakeLists files of my arborescence
2. the source file containing the main() associated to the target

I can use whole project search to eventually locate the target definition, then find the .cc files associated and navigate inside, but I sincerely think there should be a simpler option to jump to the source of the target you just selected.

May you help me finding it?

Best regards,

(edit: same question reworded in 2019)

Comment: Does the name of the target match the name of the .cc file that contains the main() for that target?

Comment: No, and that's really why I need some tool to analyse the CMakeList.txt and pair the main() source file with the EXE.